# Matrix valued word embeddings for natural language processing

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, machine-learning

In natural language processing, an area of machine learning, one would like to represent words as objects that can easily be understood and manipulated using machine learning. A word embedding is a function that represents words as objects that can be processed using machine learning, and word embeddings typically are functions from sets of words to real vector spaces.

It seems like representing words as elements of a real vector space may be suboptimal. In natural language processing, words tend to have multiple meanings and can occur in a variety of contexts. A function mapping words to vectors may be good at encoding a specific meaning of a word that occurs in a specific context, but words tend to have multiple meanings, and it seems suboptimal to represent a word with many different meanings as a vector. It seems better to represent words as collections of vectors, and matrices are good at encapsulating collections of vectors. There are several ways that a matrix could represent all of the meanings of a word combined while vectors could represent the individual meanings of the word including the following:

1. A matrix $A$ could represent all of the meanings of a word together while the vectors
   $Au_1,\dots,Au_r$ could represent the individual meanings of the word.
2. Suppose that $(v_1,\dots,v_r)$ are vectors. Then $P=v_1v_1^\ast+\dots+v_1v_r^\ast$ is a positive semidefinite matrix that represents all of the vectors $v_1,\dots,v_r$ ($P$ is analogous to a mixed state in quantum information theory). In natural language processing, $v_1,\dots,v_r$ could represent the specific meanings and specific contexts of a word while $P$ could represent all of the meanings and contexts of the word combined.
3. One could also represent the individual meanings and contexts of the word as rank-1 matrices while the word with all of its meanings and contexts could be represented as a higher rank matrix.

A matrix-valued word embedding that represents words as matrices may also be more advantageous since matrices have additional structure that vector spaces do not have.

Since matrix-valued word embeddings neatly organize the individual meanings of words, one should expect for the inner workings of matrix-valued word embeddings to be more interpretable by humans than vector-valued word embeddings.

Since matrix-valued word embeddings organize words neatly, they may perform better in natural language processing applications for the same reason that convolutional neural networks outperform   plain feedforward neural networks in image processing tasks (but this hypothesis needs to be verified using experiments).

Suppose that $A$ is a finite set and $a_1\dots a_n\in A^*$ is a string.
Then I am looking for functions $f:A\rightarrow M_{c,d}(K)$ that is most likely produced probabilistically from $a_1\dots a_n,A$ where $c,d$ are natural number and $K\in\{\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C},\mathbb{H}\}$ (we often have $c=d$).

Here are some things that I would like from a matrix-valued word embedding.

1. Similar words are represented by nearby matrices: If $a,b$ are similar words, then
   $\frac{|\langle f(a),f(b)\rangle|}{\|f(a)\|_2\cdot\|f(b)\|_2}$ should be near 1. Here, $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ denotes the Frobenius inner product while $\|\cdot\|_2$ denotes the Frobenius norm.
2. Low-rank: The quotient $\text{Rank}(f(a))/\max(c,d)$ should be small. This is because the variation in the meanings of a specific word is much less than the variation in the meanings of all possible words.
3. Near pseudo-determinism: If one were to train two word embeddings $f,g:A\rightarrow M_{c,d}(K)$ on the same or a similar data set, then there should be invertible linear transformations $R,S$ where
   $Rf(a)S\approx g(a)$ for most $a\in A$.
4. Contextual embeddings: Given a sequence of tokens $a_1,\dots,a_r$ representing text, and a word embedding $f:A\rightarrow M_{c,d}(K)$, one should be able to construct vectors $v_1,\dots,v_r\in K^{\max(c,d)}$ from the matrices $f(a_1),\dots,f(a_r)$ and perhaps a small amount of additional structure. The vectors $v_1,\dots,v_r$ should be considered as a contextual embedding of the text $a_1,\dots,a_r$ in the sense that nearly all of the meaning behind $a_1,\dots,a_r$ should be encapsulated in the sequence $v_1,\dots,v_r$.

How might one construct a matrix-valued word embedding?

So far I have not found any kind of matrix-valued word embedding other than my own, but I am sure that it is feasible to construct other matrix-valued word embeddings. You should feel free to produce a word embedding with or without using neural networks (on MathOverflow the answerers may favor an approach that does not use neural networks).

Example A: MPO word pre-embeddings: This is my own example of a word embedding. Let $K\in\{\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C},\mathbb{H}\}$. Let $a_1,\dots,a_r\in A$ be a sequence of elements, and let
$f:A\rightarrow M_d(K)$ be the fitness function
$$L_{a_1\dots a_r;p,K}(f)=\frac{\rho(f(a_1)\dots f(a_r))^{1/r}}{\|f(a_1)f(a_1)^*+\dots+f(a_r)f(a_r)^*\|_p^{1/2}}.$$
Here, $\rho(X)$ denotes the spectral radius of $X$ while $\|X\|_p$ denotes the Schatten $p$-norm of $X$. We say that $f$ is an MPO-word pre-embedding for the fitness function $f$ if the value $L_{a_1\dots a_r;p,K}(f)$ is locally optimized.

If we train the pre-embedding correctly and everything goes right, then trained MPO word embedding will not depend very much on the initialization of $f$, so we can say that the process of obtaining our word embedding exhibits some pseudodeterminism.

Example B: Word embeddings from neural networks. One should be able to upgrade any word embedding algorithm to a matrix-valued word embedding algorithm simply by considering matrices as degree 2 tensors and requiring all the weight matrices in the neural network to be tensor products $A\otimes B$ or tensor sums $A\oplus B$. I have not tested these word embeddings, so I cannot tell you how well they work or what other techniques one should use for these embeddings.